# Jquery How to override/remove a particular class when multiple class is assigned to a id

Tags: jquery

I have an html contains a div element with list,

```
<div id='tree'>
<ul>
<li id='1' class='folder expand'>1</li>
<li id='2'>2</li>
<li id='3' >3</li>
<li id='4'>4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to find

1.If the li element has class 'folder'?

```
$('#tree li').live('click',function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('folder')){
      if($(this).hasClass('expand')){
        $(this).removeClass('expand').addClass('cl');
        }
      else{
        $(this).removeClass('cl').addClass('expand');
        }
            }
}
```

This code doesn't work. It always go to the else condition.

2.In the above I want to override the class 'expand' with 'collapse'.How to remove only that name matching class??

Comment: cant you use .toggleClass() ?

Comment: Looks like your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qYwkR/. But I would agree with using `toggleClass()` and `on()`, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong with that code, it should work as given. But you don't need to see what classes there are if you only intend to toggle them. All of the above can be simplified into

```
$('#tree li.folder').live('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand cl");
});
```

Additionally, since [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated (and in fact *entirely removed* in jQuery 1.9) the above should be written using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#tree').on('click', 'li.folder', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand cl");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.  You should change your "live" listener to "on" since "live" is being deprecated.

Here's a working version of the decision tree with alerts to help you find where you are

```
$(document).on('click', '#tree li', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('folder')){
      if($(this).hasClass('expand')){
        $(this).removeClass('expand').addClass('cl');
        alert("i have folder and expand classes");
      }
      else{
        $(this).addClass('expand');
          alert("i have folder, but not expand classes");
      }
    }
    else{
        alert("I have no folder class");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pA4Vx/5/)